# Get Hardware Information for HWs that is not installed

Tags: winapi, hardware

I am pretty sure how to retrieve hardware information with WMI classes. but WMIs have a big limitation: **They Just can get information for installed hardwares**.

I need to retrieve information about CPU (model,speed,etc..),Video Card, Sound Card, USB Ports, etc. I found a really good software ([HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com)) that can do this even the drivers for hardware parts is not installed. It seems that HWiNFO uses a internal database to give a name for each hardware part.

So is there any free library/DLL/component that can do this in **Windows XP or higher**

**Note:**

Although HWiNFO SDK seems good, it's not free. So it doesn't exist! ;)

I need a free library.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 0):

HWiNFO32 has an SDK for you to integrate their component into your software.

http://www.hwinfo.com/sdk.html

Comment: Hah, ok, then I'm at a loss too.