# Hardware Information

Tags: windows, hardware

How can i detect/collect system Hardware information?
there is an [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617421/get-hardware-information-for-hws-that-is-not-installed) on 2009. I don't want to use WMI . HWInfo is excellent but SDK is not free  , is there any Free Library for this aim?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to spawn a process and use `msinfo32` in [command line mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300887)

Answer (score 0):

> you can get all hardware and component information by this process
>
> click on  start -> all programs-> accessories -> system tools ->
>   system information
>
> or can use command in run
>
> type-> msinfo32